# On finding an upper bound on the error of a sparse approximation

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, inequalities, signal-analysis, geometric-inequalities

I posted this question on math.stackexchange earlier, but didn't see any response. So, I am posting it here, in case someone else has an answer.
Original question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4443845/on-finding-an-upper-bound-on-the-error-of-a-sparse-approximation

---

$x \in R^n$ is a non-negative vector such that $ \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = 1$ ($\forall i, 0 \le x_i \le 1$).

The components are ordered:  $x_1 \ge x_2 \ldots \ge x_n$.

We are also given :  $ \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 \ge t$ for some constant $t$ ($0 \le t \le 1$).

Clearly, the larger the constant $t$, the more concentrated the components $x_i$ are going to become.

I want to make a claim on the approximate sparsity of $x$.
In other words, I want to place an upper bound on the total energy taken up by the smallest $(n-K)$ components.

Say, something like : there exists an integer $K(t)$, $1 \le K \le n$, such that

$$ \sum_{i =K+1}^n x_i^2 \le \phi(t) $$ where $\phi(t)$ is some decreasing function of $t$.

How do I get such a relation?

Comment: You posted your question on Math.SE yesterday, it might have been a good idea to wait a bit longer maybe. In any case, you can get something -- most likely not very tight (ignoring the trivial, uninteresting choice $K=n$) by setting $K=1$: $$\sum_{i=2}^n x_i^2 \leq \|x\|_2^2 - t^2 \leq 1-t^2$$ This is because $t\leq \|x\|_2^2 \leq \|x\|_1\cdot \|x\|_\infty = 1\cdot x_1$, so $x_1^2 \geq t^2$.

Comment: Thanks, Clement. As you pointed out, this bound is indeed loose. If $t=0.1$, then the bound becomes $0.99$. Since the actual purpose of getting the bound is to be able to ignore those low energy dimensions, 0.99 will not work. On the other hand, for reasonably large number of dimensions, say $n=10^3$, and $t=10^{-1}$, experiments seem to suggest that a much tighter bound should exist.

Comment: Check out section "2.1 Sparsity and Compressibility" in the book by  Foucart and  Rauhut "A Mathematical Introduction to Compressive Sensing". It contains many results of this kind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take any integer $k\in[1,n]$ and any $t\in[1/2,1]$. Consider the problem of finding the exact upper bound on $\sum_{i=k+1}^n x_i^2$ given the conditions
\begin{equation*}
    x_1\ge\cdots\ge x_n\ge0,\quad\sum_{i=1}^n x_i=1,\quad\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2=t. \tag{10}\label{10}
\end{equation*}
By continuity and compactness, there is a maximizer $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ of $\sum_{i=k+1}^n x_i^2$ given the conditions \eqref{10}. In what follows, let $x$ be such a maximizer (unless specified otherwise).

The cases when $n=k$ or $t=1$ are trivial: then conditions \eqref{10} imply $\sum_{i=k+1}^n x_i^2=0$. So, assume $n\ge k+1$ and $t\in[0,1)$. Then there is some integer $i\in[k+1,n]$ such that $x_i>0$. Indeed, if $x_1=\sqrt t$, $x_2=\cdots=x_{k+1}=\dfrac{1-\sqrt t}k$, and $x_i=0$ for $i>k+1$, then conditions \eqref{10} hold and $\sum_{i=k+1}^n x_i^2>0$.
So,
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{i=k+1}^n x_i^2>0  \tag{11}\label{11}
\end{equation*}
for the maximizer $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ of $\sum_{i=k+1}^n x_i^2$.

To obtain a contradiction, suppose that the maximizer $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is such that the $x_i$'s take at least three distinct values $u_1,u_2,u_3$ with respective multiplicities $m_1,m_2,m_3$ such that $u_1>u_2>u_3>0$. Without loss of generality, the "run" $R_3:=\{i\colon x_i=u_3\}$ of the repeated value $u_3$ is the rightmost run of a strictly positive value; that is, if $i_3:=\max R_3$, then $x_i=0$ for all $i>i_3$. So, in view of \eqref{11}, $i_3\ge k+1$.
Let us apply respective infinitesimal changes $\dfrac{du_1}{m_1},\dfrac{du_2}{m_2},\dfrac{du_3}{m_3}$ to $u_1,u_2,u_3$ such that
\begin{equation*}
    du_1+du_2+du_3=0,\quad u_1du_1+u_2du_2+u_3du_3=0,\quad u_3du_3>0; \tag{12}\label{12}
\end{equation*}
to satisfy conditions \eqref{12}, let
\begin{equation*}
    du_3>0,\quad du_2:=-\frac{u_1-u_3}{u_1-u_2}\,du_3, \quad du_1:=\frac{u_2-u_3}{u_1-u_2}\,du_3. 
\end{equation*}
Then the conditions \eqref{10} will continue to hold, for $u_1+\dfrac{du_1}{m_1},u_2+\dfrac{du_2}{m_2},u_3+\dfrac{du_3}{m_3}$ in place of $u_1,u_2,u_3$, whereas the target sum $\sum_{i=k+1}^n x_i^2$ will strictly increase (since $i_3\ge k+1$),
which will contradict the assumption that $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is a maximizer.

Thus, the $x_i$'s take at most two distinct values $u,v$ such that $u\ge v>0$. So, for some integers $j\in[1,k]$ and $l\ge1$ we have
\begin{equation*}
    x_1=\cdots=x_j=u,\quad x_{j+1}=\cdots=x_{k+l}=v, \quad x_i=0\text{ for }i>k+l. 
\end{equation*}
If $j\ge2$, then the condition $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i=1$ in \eqref{10} implies $u<\frac12$ and hence $x_i<\frac12$ for all $i$, so that $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2<\frac12\,\sum_{i=1}^n x_i=\frac12\le t$, which contradicts the condition $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2=t$ in \eqref{10}. So, $j=1$ and we have
\begin{equation*}
    x_1=u,\quad x_2=\cdots=x_{k+l}=v, \quad x_i=0\text{ for }i>k+l. 
\end{equation*}
Now the equations $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i=1$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2=t$ become $u+(k+l-1)v=1$ and $u^2+(k+l-1)v^2=t$. Solving the latter two equations for $u$ and $v$, we see that the maximum
of $\sum_{i=k+1}^n x_i^2$ given the conditions \eqref{10} is of the form
\begin{equation*}
    M_k(l):=\frac l{(k+l)^2}\,\Big(1-\sqrt{1-\frac{k+l}{k+l-1}\,(1-t)}\Big)^2
\end{equation*}
for some integer $l\ge1$. We shall assume that $n\ge k+l$, not to let $n$ play an essential role.

Now, to get the maximum of $\sum_{i=k+1}^n x_i^2$ given \eqref{10},
it remains to maximize $M_k(l)$ in $l$. This maximization seems rather complicated to be done explicitly, even though the defining expression for $M_k(l)$ is algebraic.

Instead of the exact maximization of $M_k(l)$ in $l$, let us get a good upper bound on $M_k(l)$. Since $\frac{k+l}{k+l-1}\le2$ and $\sqrt z\ge z$ for $z\in[0,1]$, we have
\begin{equation*}
    M_k(l)\le\frac l{(k+l)^2}\,2^2(1-t)^2\le\frac{(1-t)^2}k. 
\end{equation*}

---

In my other answer on this page, it was shown (see (3) there, with $s=t$ when $t\in[1/2,1]$) that no upper bound on $\sum_{i=k+1}^n x_i^2$ given \eqref{10} can be better than $\asymp \frac{(1-t)^2}k$ for $t\in[1/2,1]$. It was also shown in that answer that the the optimal upper bound on $\sum_{i=k+1}^n x_i^2$ is $\asymp\dfrac1k$ for $t\in[0,1/2]$.

> Thus, the optimal upper bound on $\sum_{i=k+1}^n x_i^2$ given \eqref{10} is $\asymp \frac{(1-t)^2}k$ for all  $t\in[0,1]$.

Answer (score 4):

Take any integer $k\ge1$ and any $t\in[0,1]$.
Let us show that
\begin{equation*}
    \sum_{i=k+1}^n x_i^2\le\frac{1-t}k. \tag{0}\label{0}
\end{equation*}

The key here is

> **Lemma 1:** For any $u\in[0,1)$ and any $x\in[0,1]$,
> \begin{equation*}
>     x^2\,1(x\le u)\le\frac u{1-u}\,(x-x^2). \tag{1}\label{1}
> \end{equation*}

*Proof:* Let $d(x):=d_u(x):=\dfrac u{1-u}\,(x-x^2)-x^2\,1(x\le u)$, the difference between the right- and left-hand sides of \eqref{1}. On the interval $[0,u]$, the function $d$ is concave. Therefore and because $d(0)=0=d(u)$, it follows that $d\ge0$ on $[0,u]$. That $d\ge0$ on $(u,1]$ is trivial. So, $d\ge0$ on $[0,1]$. That is, \eqref{1} does hold. $\quad\Box$

By Lemma 1 and in view of the conditions $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i=1$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\ge t$,
\begin{equation*}
    \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\,1(x_i\le u)\le\frac u{1-u}\,\Big(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i-\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\Big)
    \le\frac u{1-u}\,(1-t). \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{equation*}
Also, for any $i\in[n]:=\{1,\dots,n\}$, the conditions $x_1\ge\cdots\ge x_n\ge0$ imply that
\begin{equation*}
    ix_i\le\sum_{j=1}^i x_j\le\sum_{j=1}^n x_j=1. 
\end{equation*}
So, for $i\in[n]$ and any integer $k\ge1$ we have the implication
\begin{equation*}
i\ge k+1\implies    x_i\le\frac1i\le\frac1{k+1}. 
\end{equation*}
So, by \eqref{2} with $u=u_k:=\dfrac1{k+1}$,
\begin{equation*}
    \sum_{i=k+1}^n x_i^2\le\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\,1(x_i\le u_k)
    \le\frac{u_k}{1-u_k}\,(1-t)=\frac{1-t}k, 
\end{equation*}
so that inequality \eqref{0} follows.

---

The bound $\dfrac{1-t}k$ in \eqref{0} is of the optimal order $\asymp\dfrac1k$ for $t\in[0,1/2]$. Indeed, take any $t\in[0,1]$ and any integer $l\ge1$. Let $p:=k+l-1$, so that $p\ge1$. Let $s:=\max(\frac12,t)$.
Let $u:=\sqrt s$ and $v:=\dfrac{1-\sqrt s}p$. Suppose that $n\ge p+1$, $x_1=u$, $x_2=\cdots=x_{p+1}=v$, and $x_i=0$ for $i>p+1$. Then $(p+1)\sqrt s\ge2\sqrt{\frac12}>1$ and hence $u>v$, so that the conditions $1\ge x_1\ge\cdots\ge x_n\ge0$ holds. The conditions $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i=1$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\ge t$ hold as well. Moreover,
\begin{equation}
        \sum_{i=k+1}^n x_i^2=lv^2=(1-\sqrt s)^2\frac l{(k+l-1)^2} \\ 
        \ge(1-\sqrt s)^2\frac l{(k+l)^2}
        \ge\frac{(1-s)^2}{16k}  \tag{3}\label{3}
\end{equation}
if $l=k$.
If now $t\in[0,1/2]$, then $s=1/2$ and hence
\begin{equation}
        \sum_{i=k+1}^n x_i^2
        \ge\frac1{64k}\asymp\dfrac1k,  
\end{equation}
as claimed.

---

In my other answer on this page, it will be shown, based on another idea, that for $t\in[1/2,1]$ -- and hence for all $t\in[0,1]$ -- the optimal upper bound on $\sum_{i=k+1}^n x_i^2$ is of the order $\dfrac{(1-t)^2}k$.